# Pass query + extra variable from model to view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm wondering what is the best way to pass a query result + a separate piece of text from a model to a view.

My model

```
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * from ci_wizard_results WHERE `tblresultrequestsource` LIKE '%".$countryqueryresult->countrytld."%' AND tblresultkioskname = '' ".$sqlkioskfilter." ORDER BY ci_wizard_results.tblresultdatetime DESC");
    $querytext = "some text"
    return $query->result();
```

Controller:

```
$data['yunbe_selectall'] = $this->wizard_model->yunbe_selectall();
```

View:

```html
<?php foreach($yunbe_selectall as $yunbe_selectallrow) { ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $yunbe_selectallrow->tblresultrefid;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $yunbe_selectallrow->tblresultdatetime;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $yunbe_selectallrow->tblresultip;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $yunbe_selectallrow->tblresultrequestsource;?></td>
```

I want to display "$querytext" into the view. I know it would be better to put each return in a different function, but since there are some complicated query's in the function to get to the result, I'd like to avoid to duplicate it.

I tried passing it as an array, but I can't manage to get it displayed.

Thanks!!

Comment: you could store the text as a property in the model and retrieve it in the controller. or make the entire return from the model an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track with an array:

```
query = $this->db->query("SELECT * from ci_wizard_results WHERE `tblresultrequestsource` LIKE '%".$countryqueryresult->countrytld."%' AND tblresultkioskname = '' ".$sqlkioskfilter." ORDER BY ci_wizard_results.tblresultdatetime DESC");
$querytext = "some text"
return array('text'=>$querytext, 'result'=>$query->result());
```

Controller:

```
$data['yunbe_selectall'] = $this->wizard_model->yunbe_selectall();
```

View:

```
<h2><?php echo $yunbe_selectall['text'];?></h2>
<?php foreach($yunbe_selectall['result'] as $yunbe_selectallrow) { ?>
```

Comment: Apparently I did something wrong when retrieving the array in my view. Your example worked right away. Thanks!!